# A2C Agent does not learn anything in a simple 2D grid world

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to implement a simple Advantage Actor Critic algorithm on a simple self-defined environment. My complete code is shown below.

It is a 10×10 grid world environment where there is

- one end state with +100 reward, and
- other end states with 0 reward.

The agent can take a maximum of 15 steps with the actions (up, down, left and right). If the agent runs out on one edge of the field, he comes out on the opposite side. For each step on the field he gets +1 reward.

The code for my Policy Value Network and the training code is shown in full below. I would expect the agent to learn over time where the +100 field is and steer specifically there so that the average reward of a trajectory converges to 100.

I have shown one run as a result below. As you can see, the Episode Reward hardly/not at all increases, but stagnates at about 15 (which is the maximum number of steps on the field, and he gets +1 reward for each step). Every now and then he hits the +100 field, but that seems more random instead of him learning over time where the field is. I would be very grateful for any hints as to why my agent is not learning.

#### 2d-world.py

```
import torch
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.distributions.categorical import Categorical
from model import PolicyValueNetwork
from torch.utils.tensorboard import SummaryWriter
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
writer = SummaryWriter()

lr = 0.01
gamma = 0.99
episodes = 1000000
normalize_targets = True
n_steps = 15

class Environment():
    def __init__(self):
        field = {
                "0": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                "1": [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
                "2": [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
                "3": [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
                "4": [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                "5": [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
                "6": [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
                "7": [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                "8": [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 100, 1, 1],
                "9": [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]}
        env = pd.DataFrame(data=field).T
        self.rewards = env.values
        n_rows = self.rewards.shape[0]
        n_cols = self.rewards.shape[1]
        self.start_points = []
        for row in range(0, n_rows):
            for col in range(0, n_cols):
                if self.rewards[row][col] == 1:
                    self.start_points.append((col, row)) # (x, y)
        self.s = self.reset()
        
    def step(self, action): # action in [0, 1, 2, 3] means ["up", "down", "left", "right"]
        
        # First we calculate the possible new positions on the field
        x = self.s[0]
        y = self.s[1] 
        nx = [x, x, 9 if x == 0 else x - 1, 0 if x == 9 else x + 1] # possible next x values
        ny = [9 if y == 0 else y - 1, 0 if y == 9 else y + 1, y, y] # possible next y values
        
        # Get next state and reward
        ns = (nx[action], ny[action]) 
        self.s = ns
        reward = self.rewards[ns[1]][ns[0]] # indexing is done like [y][x]
        
        # Calculate done signal
        done = reward == 100 or reward == 0
        
        return ns, reward, done
    
    def reset(self):
        i = np.random.choice(list(range(0, len(self.start_points))))
        self.s = self.start_points[i]
        return self.s

# Get cuda device
device = torch.device(0)

# Instantiate model
model = PolicyValueNetwork()
model.to(device)

# Optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=lr)
#optimizer = torch.optim.RMSprop(model.parameters())        

# Loss function for value loss
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss(reduction="sum")
          
# Set environment
env = Environment()
 
for episode in range(0, episodes):
    
    state = env.reset()
    
    # Set up arrays for this episode
    values = []
    log_probs = []
    rewards = []
    states = []
    for i in range(0, n_steps): 
       
        states.append(state)
        
        # Create tensor for current state
        state_tensor = torch.tensor(data=state).float().to(device)
        
        # Get policy and value from model
        probs, value = model(state_tensor)
        values.append(value)
        categorical = Categorical(probs=probs)
        
        # Sample an action
        a = categorical.sample()
        log_prob = categorical.log_prob(a)
        log_probs.append(log_prob)
        
        # Execute step in the environment
        state, reward, done = env.step(a.item())
        rewards.append(reward)
        
        
        if done:
            break
     
    
    # Calculate discounted returns
    state_tensor = torch.tensor(data=state).float().to(device)
    _, value = model(state_tensor)
    R = 0.0 if done else value.item()
    T = len(values)
    targets = np.empty(T, dtype=np.float32)
    for i in reversed(range(T)):
        targets[i] = R = rewards[i] + gamma * R
    
    # Normalize discounted returns alias targets
    if normalize_targets:
        targets = scaler.fit_transform(targets.reshape(-1,1))
    targets = torch.tensor(data=targets).to(device).squeeze()

    # Calculate advantages
    values = torch.stack(values).squeeze()
    advantages = targets - values
    
    # Calculate policy loss
    log_probs = torch.stack(log_probs).squeeze()
    policy_loss = torch.sum(-advantages.detach() * log_probs)
    
    # Value loss
    value_loss = loss_fn(values, targets)
    
    # Backpropagation
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    policy_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    value_loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    
    
    # Logging with tensorboard
    writer.add_scalar("Episode Reward", sum(rewards), episode)
    writer.add_scalar("Episode Policy Loss", policy_loss.item(), episode)
    writer.add_scalar("Episode Value Loss", value_loss.item(), episode)
```

#### model.py

```
import torch.nn as nn

# Neural network            
class PolicyValueNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PolicyValueNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.lin1 = nn.Linear(in_features=2, out_features=128, bias=True)
        self.policy = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=4, bias=True)
        self.value = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=1, bias=True)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=0)
    
    def forward(self, inp):
        out1 = self.lin1(inp)
        relu1 = self.relu(out1)
        policy = self.policy(relu1)
        value = self.value(relu1)
        probs = self.softmax(policy)
        return probs, value
```

#### Results (Returns for each episode, about 45k episodes)

[image: Episode Returns]

Comment: Not sure if the suggestion comes too late, but in any case...Seems like your reward function is not appealing for your agent in order to explore, it rather prefers to assure 15 rewards probably going onward and forth between two states (local optima). You want the agent to reach the 100 points reward in the minimum possible steps, and for such it needs to be under pressure. Try rewarding the agent with a -1 for every single step.